# winetricks unable to find mfc40

Tags: wine, winetricks

if I run:

```
winetricks mfc40
```

I get this output:

```
Executing w_do_call mfc40
Executing load_mfc40
Downloading http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vc/mfc40.cab to /home/marty/.cache/winetricks/mfc40
--2016-03-30 23:53:39--  http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vc/mfc40.cab
Resolving activex.microsoft.com (activex.microsoft.com)... 92.122.227.59, 92.122.227.58
Connecting to activex.microsoft.com (activex.microsoft.com)|92.122.227.59|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-03-30 23:53:39 ERROR 404: Not Found.

------------------------------------------------------
Downloading http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vc/mfc40.cab failed
------------------------------------------------------
```

Apperently a dead link, is there an alternative way to get this DLL working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks
./winetricks mfc40
```